# Android: why is return used in this instance?

Tags: java, android, return, return-value

So I followed this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S3Z4e7KgNdU&list=PL2F07DBCDCC01493A&index=117

The tutorial details how to write a method to create an entry in an sqlite database. At the end of the tutorial, he adds that the method should not be void and that the following line:

```
ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

should actually be returned. It seems that this would have worked without making it a return statement.

I have seen this happen a lot in java examples were processes are carried out and a return statement is added that seems (to me as a newbie) pointless.

Can someone explain the point of a return statement in this case?

Comment: The `insert(...)` method actually returns a `long` to indicate how many rows have been affected (as do other DB methods). In the case of `insert(...)` it returns the number of records which have been inserted. Technically your method which calls `insert(...)` doesn't need to return the `long` but it is good practice to do so just in case other parts of your code might need to know the result.

Comment: I stand corrected - as Kasper states, the return value is the row ID that was inserted. The argument still holds true though - it is good practice to return the return values of the DB methods such as insert, delete, replace, update etc.

Comment: @MichaelAndroidNewbie : As I said in my second comment it is, in fact, the row ID as `insert(...)` can only insert one row at a time. As Kasper points out it will be -1 if there was an error which technically means 0 rows were inserted - as long as you get a result other than -1 you know it has been successful. The `replace(...)` method only works on one row and also returns row ID or -1. The `delete(...)` and `update(...)` methods however work with multiple rows and return the number of affected rows (as an `int`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the 'insert' function returns a 'long' value, which is the ID of the new row that was inserted (if everything was ok), or it will return -1, if some sort of error happened.

It's good to have the database ID of the item if you at some point later in the code, need it.
That's why it should return a 'long' instead of being 'void'.